# Como fazer para Google não indexar este script?

Tags: wordpress, google, script, índices

Olá!

Comecei a utilizar um script no meu site wordpress para exibir anuncios de uma rede de publicidade, o problema é que quando fui ao webmaster tools reparei que o script está a fazer com que o google não indexe as minhas páginas.

Estive a procurar e a solução é fazer com que o script não seja detectável pelos motores de busca.

Posso alterar o código do script para colocar um "noindex" ou coisa do gênero para fazer isso?

Aqui fica o código:

```
   <!-- adnow -->
    Recomendámos
    <div id="SC_TBlock_119595" class="SC_TBlock">loading...</div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">var SC_CId = "XXXXX",SC_Domain="n.ads2-adnow.com";SC_Start_119595=(new Date).getTime();</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://st-n.ads2-adnow.com/js/adv_out.js"></script> 
    <!--fim adnow -->
```

Alguém me pode colocar o código aqui editado de forma que isso seja possível?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar as tags googleon e googleoff. Essas tags dizem para o Google não indexar, não seguir e não criar descrições com determinado trecho do seu conteúdo.

```html
<!--googleoff: all-->
 <!-- adnow -->
    Recomendámos
    <div id="SC_TBlock_119595" class="SC_TBlock">loading...</div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">var SC_CId = "XXXXX",SC_Domain="n.ads2-adnow.com";SC_Start_119595=(new Date).getTime();</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://st-n.ads2-adnow.com/js/adv_out.js"></script> 
    <!--fim adnow -->
<!--googleon: all-->
```

Fonte: https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/googleon-googleoff-restringir-indexacao/